# How to use google maps API to get current address of the user?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am working to build one website where I have to implement the Google map. When the user opens the webpage it should point the pin of the user´s current location in map and return full address, latitude and longitude values as in the mock up below as well as when the user drags the pin to other place it should show the new address, latitude and longitude value as well:

[image: placeholder]

I went through the documentations and examples and found that I have to use reverse geocoding. I am so new in programming that I did not figure out the exact way to do. I hope keeping on the mind that I am amateur in programming you will consider my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend looking at the [**HTML5 Geolocation**](http://www.w3schools.com/htmL/html5_geolocation.asp) methods
This can provide the longitude and latitude and can also shown on a map.

The only problems I see that it requires to be allowed by the user on the specific browser instance and it might sometimes only show the ISP address.

I found this post to compliment Geo Location that might be helpful as well

[Geolocation In Web Browsers To Find Location & Google Maps Examples](http://robertnyman.com/2010/03/15/geolocation-in-web-browsers-to-find-location-google-maps-examples/)

Comment: I was thinking to do that way. But in this I did not find the way to get the string value of address and even in the example that you provided me.